# Updating a table from a temporary table where clause error in MySql Community

Tags: mysql, update, mysql-workbench, where, temporary-tables

I am trying to update an existing table named "residential_summary" from a temporary table called "a". I can query the temporary table a but when I try to use it in an update statement I get

`Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'a.meter' in 'where clause'`

Is this something that you just cant do or am I somehow misinterpreting the syntax for Update? Why is my column unknown? Please elaborate because I am new at databases. Here is my code and a screenshot.

```
UPDATE residential_summary
SET residential_summary.load_factor = a.load_factor
WHERE a.meter = residential_summary.meter;
```

[image]

Comment: Since your query doesn't include a reference to temporary table `a`, the engine has no idea what `a` is. I'm a SQL Server guy, not 100% sure of MySQL syntax for this.

Comment: How do you reference a temporary table? Again, I am very new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL queries always explicitly reference their tables by name, apart from any references to the columns in the tables. Since your query doesn't include a reference to the 'a' table explicitly as a table, the engine has no idea what `a` is. I'm a SQL Server guy, but based on some quick Googling of "MySQL update join", looks like the statement should be:

```
UPDATE residential_summary
         INNER JOIN a ON residential_summary.meter = a.meter
SET residential_summary.load_factor = a.load_factor;
```

The `UPDATE ... INNER JOIN ...` tells the engine that this query will be working with the `residential_summary` and `a` tables. The INNER JOIN ties `residential_summary` and `a` together based on the values of `meter` in both tables, so that only `residential_summary` rows that have a matching row in `a` will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your query misses mentioning of `a` table after `update`.
This should work (I only added `a`)

```
UPDATE residential_summary, a
SET residential_summary.load_factor = a.load_factor
WHERE a.meter = residential_summary.meter;
```